# Centering Table with Column Width in Two-column layout

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have the following table which I want to put in the center of the two-column 
manuscript. But it failed although I already put the asterisk in the `\begin{table*}` command.

```
\begin{table*}
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{7}{r}@{}}
  \toprule
  & $z_{6}$ & $z_{8}$ & $z_{9}$ & $z_{11}$ & $z_{13}$ & $z_{14}$ \\
  \midrule
  fileA & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.08 & 0.79 & 0.08  \\
  fileB & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.13 & 0.00 & 0.84 & 0.00  \\
  fileC & 0.00 & 0.39 & 0.02 & 0.49 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  fileD & 0.75 & 0.08 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  \bottomrule                             
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add a complete minimal working example (MWE) tex document and describe what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Note that `\columnwidth` is only *half* of the two-column size of `tabular*`. Adding `\centering` before `\begin{tabular*}` will center the table.

Comment: I think what Stephan is saying is that you would probably like to try replacing \columnwidth by \textwidth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full width of the text area is `\textwidth` not `\columnwidth` so as shown in the first example below you could specify that to `tabular*` personally I think that makes the table look rather spaced out and it is better to set it to its natural width using `tabular` and then centre the result, as shown in the second table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\def\a{One two three four. }
\def\b{Red Yellow Green Blue. }
\def\c{\a\a\b\b\par\b\a\b\a\b\b\a\par}

\begin{document}
\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{7}{r}@{}}
  \toprule
  & $z_{6}$ & $z_{8}$ & $z_{9}$ & $z_{11}$ & $z_{13}$ & $z_{14}$ \\
  \midrule
  fileA & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.08 & 0.79 & 0.08  \\
  fileB & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.13 & 0.00 & 0.84 & 0.00  \\
  fileC & 0.00 & 0.39 & 0.02 & 0.49 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  fileD & 0.75 & 0.08 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  \bottomrule                             
\end{tabular*}
\caption{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{7}{r}}
  \toprule
  & $z_{6}$ & $z_{8}$ & $z_{9}$ & $z_{11}$ & $z_{13}$ & $z_{14}$ \\
  \midrule
  fileA & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.08 & 0.79 & 0.08  \\
  fileB & 0.01 & 0.00 & 0.13 & 0.00 & 0.84 & 0.00  \\
  fileC & 0.00 & 0.39 & 0.02 & 0.49 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  fileD & 0.75 & 0.08 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
  \bottomrule                             
\end{tabular}
\caption{tabular}
\end{table*}

\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c\c


\end{document}
```